# Intel XDK side panel scrolls only if long enough at initalization

Tags: scroll, mobile-application, appframework

I'm using the app mobile framework and think I've found a bug regarding the scrollbar. If the side panel is long enough to scroll at initialization, I can scroll after rotation. However, if the app starts in portrait mode (no scroll required) and then I rotate to landscape, then there is no scrollbar. Here's the relevant code below. Right now I have a bunch of "hello's" so that the scrollbar is always there. How to get it to scroll without them?

```
<div class="inner-element uib_w_21 uib_sidebar rightbar bar-bg" data-uib="layout/right_sidebar" data-ver="0" data-anim="{'style':'overlap', 'v':200, 'side':'right'}" id="rightPanel">
    <div class="sidebar-content">

        <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_12 row-height-12" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
            <div class="col uib_col_13 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                    <div class="widget uib_w_22 d-margins" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
                        <div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Settings:</p>
                        </div>
                    </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="uib_shim"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_13 row-height-13" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
            <div class="col uib_col_14 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                    <div class="widget uib_w_23 d-margins" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
                        <div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>
                        <div id=rightpanel_container style="overflow-y:scroll">
                            <p> hello there! hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!hello there!</p>
                            <div>
                                <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                    <label for="startdate">Start Date:</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate" value="2014-02-01" class="jq-ui-forms">
                                    <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                    <label for="enddate">End Date:</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate" value="2014-03-01" class="jq-ui-forms">
                                    <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                <div id="fieldOptions">
                                    Field Options Go here
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                <a class="button widget uib_w_26 d-margins icon error" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="0" id="removeFavorite-button">Remove Stock from Favorites</a>
                                <a class="button widget uib_w_27 d-margins icon add" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="0" id="addFavorite-button">Add Stock to Favorites</a>
                                <a class="button widget uib_w_18 d-margins icon check" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="0" id="settings-done-button">Done</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="uib_shim"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this limitation is in App Framework designs only. It seems to work correctly if one of the other UI frameworks is chosen.

I've filed a bug and we'll see about getting it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-enabling native scrolling (this may not be a perfect solution for all devices):

```
af.feat.nativeTouchScroll = true;
```

More info: http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_scrolling